# Is $\sin (1+ \frac{x}{n})$ decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, trigonometry

Is $\sin (1+ \frac{x}{n})$ decreasing function , x any element in bounded interval of real numbers?

My attempt: Let the interval in which x belongs be bounded by m(lower bound),M(upper bound)

$1+ \frac{x}{n}$ --> decreasing function for all $n>x > m$

Sin is increasing function in interval $[0, \pi/2]$

composition of increasing and decreasing function --> decreasing function.

So $\sin (1+ \frac{x}{n})$ decreasing function for $n>m$

But in wolfram plotting (by putting values x = 1, 2 ,3 --> sin (1+1/n), sin(1+2/n),...), i am not seeing decreasing function but some sin like oscillating function. Seems i did some mistake. Pls correct me...
http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=74c4d9c719a83b7ef727a22ad471f80d

Comment: You will see the oscillating function because sin is increasing function in interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi m,\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi m]$ where $m$ is an integer. Therefore as you change $x$ and $1+\frac{x}{n}$ falls into these intervals, it increases. and decreases everywhere else.

Comment: @prog_SAHILcan u tell me is my proof that sin(1+x/n) is decreasing function for x>m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've proved that when you fix $x$ and increase $n$ the function decreases (for $n$ sufficiently large in terms of $x$). But then in Wolfram you fixed $n$ and increased $x$, which is the wrong way round. You should be plotting $\sin(1+x), \sin(1+x/2),\sin(1+x/3),...$

Comment: got it ... thank you